# TextOverflow.visible vs TextOverflow.clip, what's the difference?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```dart
Text(
  'This question is posted on Stack Overflow',
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60),
  overflow: TextOverflow.clip, // TextOverflow.visible does the same thing
  softWrap: false,
)
```

So, what's the difference between `TextOverflow.visible` and `TextOverflow.clip` as they both seem to do the same job.

**Note**: Please don't just share what's written in the docs, provide a sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextOverflow.visible` does not clip overflow text like `TextOverflow.clip`

For example, let's create these two containers:

```
// Container with visible text
Container(
    color: Colors.red,
    width: 100,
    height: 30,
    child: Text(
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit',
        overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
    ),
),

// Container with clipped text
Container(
    color: Colors.red,
    width: 100,
    height: 30,
    child: Text(
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit',
        overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
    ),
),
```

And there we can see the difference:
[image]